How best to transport Uttarkuru Firestones in bulk
Uttarkuru Firestones are magical rocks that occur only on the continent of Uttarkuru, that look and weigh much like irregular pebbles of polished haematite.

Image from https://www.purnellagencies.com.au/product/hematite-2/
They have the property that when exposed to visible light and/or drafts, they become hot, glow in a variety of colours and emit a flame of the same colour as the stone's glow, much as if they were an equivalent mass of burning anthracite coal, except that they never burn out.  The heat and glow is proportional to the stimulation they receive.
Obviously, the presence of other firestones nearby mean that they can be triggered by each-other to begin 'burning'.  While they can be used to provide heat, they cannot provide any elements for a chemical reaction as coal could, so they cannot be used as a substitute for coal in the smelting of iron ore to iron.
If firestones are separated from one-another, they can be quenched in water, or covered with sand, at which point they will cool again, but a bulk mass of firestones drenched in water may continue to emit heat by mutual light activation, resulting in the water boiling away, or if covered in sand in bulk, the sand may melt, and its glow would continue the stones' activation.  They are usually transported by being placed individually in dark, windproof, opaque containers.  Firestones cannot be safely transported bundled together, because if the container in which a number of firestones is carried together is jostled, the triboluminescence of the stones banging against one-another can be sufficient to activate them to emit heat, thus activating the nearby stones.
The merchants who want to transport firestones want to do so with the minimum of expense, time and effort, and want to be able to pack the greatest number of firestones into the smallest volume and least mass.  So, in a society with technology and resources roughly equivalent to early 1700's England, what is the cheapest, least labour-intensive, quickest, lightest and least bulky way to prepare firestones for safe bulk transport?
While the firestones are magic, I'm looking for a non-magical answer.

Which kind of light are they activated from? Visible only? IR? UV?

@L.Dutch Visible light.

While you can't make steel, you could literally kickstart the industrial age with this.

You can coat them in molten wax loaded with charcoal or pitch. Then, once the wax/pitch has solidified, put the coated firestones in the usual wooden crate together with sawdust.
The charcoal load will absorb visible light, while the wax/pitch coating will damp and absorb the impacts together with the sawdust.
To remove the wax/pitch before usage, a single scratch will start a positive loop which will melt it away.

You essentially have an unlimited source of heat and light. You literally have steam age technology. You build a steam engine. In this case this is literally  a nuclear power plant. You use the energy generated by the stones to move it.

a bulk mass of firestones drenched in water may continue to emit heat by mutual light activation, resulting in the water boiling away,

You basically use water as a moderator. You can recondense and reuse the water, increasing flow if the stones get too hot. Or better yet, build freshwater canals and use them as a large heat sink for firestone powered boats.
Even if you're generating 'too much' energy, you basically have an unlimited source of it - so you could use the stones for one way, use them to power up giant flywheels and use them for the return leg.
I've not enough coffee for throwing together a crappy image but consider a rail system - you essentially have a steam train which is firestone powered, each carrying a rail car that's essentially a 'small' self contained firestone reactor. It has a carefully selected amount of firestone in a jettsonable metal container, a water source and a way to store or dump excess energy. You could power water pumps using the steam generator, or a fan, so active cooling would be an option too.
Mass and volume dosen't matter when you literally have a nuclear powered steam train or ship.
Better yet, build a giant cargo ship powered by this. You have unlimited range, only tempered by the need to feed the crew and maintain the ship. Store the stones in tanks of water, like a modern fishing vessel, and use either the movement of the ship, or firestone reactor powered coolers to keep the water at a lower temperature.
You might even be able to build a 'simple' jet engine, considering you can generate copious amounts of heat - but I'll leave that, and the implications for the laws of thermodynamics, as an exercise to the reader

While that may be a very 'good' way of transporting firestones, it isn't quick or cheap.

Technically, effectively free - if you think about it.  And potentially a lot faster than horses or other means.  It just uses the 'drawbacks' of the substance as an advantage. Boats and trains were relatively normal/cheap modes of transportation, and we're just replacing the fuel source. You might even transport regular cargo with these things. And steam is certainly faster than horses or anything else.

I upvoted this answer because you are correct: the firestones can eventually transport themselves.  However, when you have merchants with a sailing ship who want to take some firestones home with them, right now, they need a solution as quickly and cheaply as possible.

Wool, in particular quarter inch felt, as long as it's of uniform density it's opaque but still soft. Individually wrap/bag the stones to minimise jostling and they won't light up. Properly fulled wool has the distinct advantage of being very fire resistant making a little warmth from the stones survivable by the packaging. Assuming bags aren't too much bigger than the stones in them you should be able to literally throw the bagged stones into a cheap crate or chest, that is not itself light tight, and that into a wagon and bounce off down the road without incident.

Layering and bubble wrap
If the stones are individually wrapped in padded leather or fabric (fleece lined) pouches it should be possible to transport them in special crates. The crate can be either top or front opening but front opening might be easier.
The first layer of stones are laid down on the base of the crate in rows and lines like dominoes with each stone in it's own individual cushioned pouch. Once the first layer is full a timber divider or shelf is slotted into the crate over the top of the first layer of stones and the process is repeated. Once the second layer of stones is complete the same thing happens again i.e another shelf is slotted into place and stones in their individual pouches are again slipped in one at a time onto the shelf until that shelf is also full. Repeat until the crate is filled to the top. Vertical movement/bouncing is constrained by the fact that each shelf is usually only tall enough to accept one and one only layer of stones. If desired? The shelves could (in theory) be done away with and the pouches just laid one on top of one other but the shelves do act as a buffer/risk reduction measure.
The point being that the stones in any one level can't 'bang' together because they are already tightly packed and individually wrapped in their own 16th century equivalent of bubble wrap and individual layers are physically separated by shelving. If considered necessary the crate itself can then be wrapped in a thick protective blanket.
Lastly and importantly stones are graded and shipped by size.  As far as is possible all stones in any one crate will be roughly the same size size so that vertical movement is limited. Also importantly the crates and pouches are designed to be re-used so that the cost of building what amounts to a crude piece of furniture is mitigated by the ability to re-use it multiple times (take the shelves out and something else can be put inside for the return trip to Uttarkuru after the stones have been delivered while the pouches can just be stored in sacks until needed again.

Bubble wrap in early 1700's England?

@L. Dutch Note my description of the 'bubble wrap in question'.

Modern bubblewrap-replacements are paper. Would be something they could make in the early industrial age

We can get really technical here, or we can go with the cheapest solution: clay.
Get some wet clay, drop an activated stone in and form the clay into a ball. The residual heat from the stone will cure the clay on the inside, then you can scrape the uncured clay off and wrap the encased stone in black cloth for shipment.
Personally I'd leave some of the wet clay on and ship them in a porous box you can keep wet. This ensures that the dry clay encasing the stones doesn't crack and let light in, and that any cracks from transmitted shock are covered and filled immediately.
And hey, it's the 1700's (equivalently). Nobody is going to care that your shipment of magical stones is a little bit... gooey. It doesn't have to be pretty, it just has to work.
I'd be more worried that one of these things gets dropped and starts melting its way through the planet. Can you add an upper limit on their heat production? If they have a lower melting point than rock (lava can be liquid as low as ~700°C/1300°F) then we're probably safe.

There is an upper limit on firestones' heat production: an equivalent mass of anthracite.  Burning coal doesn't go china-syndrome, and neither will firestones.  As soon as they're out of a draft, they'll start cooling down, and as soon as they're out of the light, they'll cool down the rest of the way.

@MontyWild "out of the light" is fine until you realize that lava glows

Yes, lava does glow, doesn't it.  However, Firestones are supposed to be a limitless coal-substitute, and burning coal with no draft isn't really going to make stone glow that much, and won't keep lava from solidifying.

Partition them, so that a stone seeing the light does not mean the whole charge is lost and must be recaptured. Small crates, layed out flat to monitor on the packaging beast, no additional wrappers, unless there is rain. Hooks on every small crate- to pull it out of the storage compartment when it starts smoldering. Maybe add some incense to have dense, highly visible smoke as soon as possible. Every carawann guard obviously has a fire hook. Then there is the last guy, whos job it is, to recapture, rewrap and rebundle escaped stones.
Warehouses are similar to army amonition storages- lots of seperation to prevent eternal blazes that nobody can come near anymore, while the stones melt into the ground, out of sight and finally out of sunlight. Obviously the stones cool down at night, so ideal trade and transport time is a night market.

Put them in water or oil
"Ignition" requires both light and drafts.  Eliminating all possible sources of light is problematic for a variety of reasons - especially being able to see what you are doing - but eliminating drafts only requires eliminating the possibility of any air contacting the surface of the stone.  Therefore, use waterproof/ oilproof double-walled containers to carry and store them in.  These may be anything from wooden water barrels to metal or other containers.
This allows the stones to be packed in on top of each other in a single container with no further packaging.  Given that haematite has a density of slightly over 5, as long as the majority of the space is packed with the rocks the water is a relatively minimal aspect of the overall mass.  Oil would reduce the mass of the packaging even further, but it depends on where the economic sweet spot exists between transporting the extra mass compared to the additional cost of whatever oils are available.
Safety instructions:

Always carry spare water/oil to allow the storage container to be topped up in case of leaks.
Always carry repair materials to fix any leaks in the container.
Always use a ladle deep enough to allow even the largest stone to remain immersed at all times when transferring between containers.


Water is transparent, and impact could still cause triboluminescence... but a dark oil is possible.

The question states that they become hot when exposed to visible lights and drafts.  Immersed in water = no drafts, making it impossible for both required conditions to be met.  (I know you said that drenching them in water is an unreliable method of extinguishing, but "drenched" and "immersed" are not the same.)  If the "become hot" condition should be an "or" statement and not an "and" statement then this stuff is almost impossible to handle.

I've clarified in the question.  It's proportional light and/or draft.

If the tiny amount of light produced by triboluminescence in the absence of any air is enough to make them heat up then they are absolutely unable to be handled - as soon as enough light falls on one to allow it to be seen by a human it will set it off.

One stone alone, if impacted by a hard object at night in still air would briefly glow and then fade.  If right next to another stone, the glow of the first would activate the second, which would in turn activate the first.  That's why they're traditionally transported individually.
